# Date not updating in setInterval

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

**here is my javascript code I didnt include HTML file because everything is simple.
time is displayed on webpage but seconds doesn't work**

```
const hour = document.querySelector(".hour");
const minute = document.querySelector(".minute");
const seconds = document.querySelector(".seconds");
const timeZone = document.querySelector(".timeZone");

const date = new Date();

setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime() {
  hour.innerHTML = date.getHours() + " : ";
  minute.innerHTML = date.getMinutes() + " : ";
  seconds.innerHTML = date.getSeconds();
}

setTime();
```

Comment: You're using a static `Date`, it's values aren't going to change. You need to create a new `Date` inside your `setTime()` method and get it's hours,minutes, and seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments mentioned, you need to move your date object into your interval function.
Otherwise when you instantiate the date object, it'll be static and the seconds wont increase.

Here is a snippet of it working.

```js
const hour = document.querySelector(".hour");
const minute = document.querySelector(".minute");
const seconds = document.querySelector(".seconds");
const timeZone = document.querySelector(".timeZone");

debugger

setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime() {
  let date = new Date();
  hour.innerHTML = date.getHours() + " : ";
  minute.innerHTML = date.getMinutes() + " : ";
  seconds.innerHTML = date.getSeconds();
}

setTime()
```

```html
<span class="hour"></span>
<span class="minute"></span>
<span class="seconds"></span>
<span class="timeZone"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much